# Изъятие координат маркера на Google Map из массива координат

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Добрый вечер господа,
появилась такая проблема.Есть множество отделений компании,каждое из них имеет свой адрес и должно быть обозначено на карте точкой.К сожалению вариант : Все точки на одной карте не подходит,и приходится делать по карте на каждую вкладку отделения.При открытии карты каждого отделения значение MAP-1 приобретает новое +1

MAP-2 к примеру.Как можно привязать координаты карты/точки к значению карты?
К примеру имея массив извлекать данные из него,но точек более 40.По этому сложно представить решение проблемы.Надеюсь сообщество Stackoverflow поможет решить данный вопрос.
Заранее спасибо!